# How to access array in render using React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am quite new to React, and while trying to figure out a coding problem, I saw this piece of code on another question (I tried asking those who answered the question but received no reply as it was answered a while back) :

```js
let theArray = []

functionName(() => {
        axios
            .get(`/api/data`)
            .then(res => {
                const newItem = {
                  id: res.data.id,
                  name: res.data.name,
                };
                theArray.push(newItem);
             })
    }, [])
```

Would anyone know how to access theArray in render()? I tried doing theArray[0].id, but got an error. I also tried this.state.theArray[0].id, but also got an error (The array has 4 elements, each having their own id and name)

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: This is what you need to use state for. Put the result in state, read it from there. And keep in mind that the value will be empty until the request has completed.

Comment: Please read the the documentation.

Comment: @Guy Incognito, thanks for mentioning the set state. I was confused about what to even search for, so this helped a lot! I managed to solve my problem by searching for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this.

```js
  const [theState, setState] = useState([])

   functionName(() => {
        axios
            .get(`/api/data`)
            .then(res => {
                const newItem = {
                  id: res.data.id,
                  name: res.data.name,
                };
                setState([...theState, newItem])
             })
    }, [])
```

Comment: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537)

Comment: Thank you for this, it helped me a lot! I was confused on what to even search for, but after you showed me the code plus introduced me to setState, it makes a lot of sense. Thank you!